# Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter, dart, widget

I am running my flutter project on Xcode but I am facing this problem:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreGraphics'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Foundation'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'MobileCoreServices'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'PinterestSDK'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'SSKeychain'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Security'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'SystemConfiguration'
Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I added the pod 'PinterestSDK' & pod 'SSKeychain' in my pod file but still is not working.

Also, I ran pod install in terminal but still is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run flutter clean in terminal. Sometime that help solve this kind of issue.